# access state parameter object inside the controller angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to access state parameter object. my config is as below

```
    .config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('app.charts-panel', {
        url: '/charts-panel/:{viewD}',
        templateUrl: 'modules/dynamic-dashboard/dynamic-dashboard-view/charts-panel/charts-panel.html',
        controller: 'chartsPanelCtrl'
    });
}])
```

i need to print my 'viewD' object. i tried to print it. result show as [object object].
how i correctly print this.

i tried to print using below code

```
    var dashboardDel=$stateParams.viewD;
$log.info(dashboardDel);
```

result show as [object object]

Comment: if that is an object, you should consider using `params` in `$stateProvider` api

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25115928/pass-object-as-parameter-in-state-go